# Fetch datas between two tags

Tags: java, regex

I have got the following string

```
   String s =  "{s}lorem ipsum{/s}
    explanation for lorem ipsum
    {s}dolar sit amet{/s}
    explanation for dolar sit amet";
```

I would like to parse it in two ways. I want to fetch the texts thats within {s}{/s} tag and texts thats not enclosed by {s}{/s}.

I tried the following code.

```
 String firstRemovePattern        = "\\{"  + "\\}";
            String replacedWithFirstPattern  = s.replaceAll(firstRemovePattern, "");
```

but the above code doesnt fetch the expected strings. How can i be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to get both parts separately:

```
\{(\w+)\}(.*?){/\1}((?:(?!\{\w+\}).)*)
```

- Group #2 will give you text in between the tags.
- Group #3 will give you text outside the tags.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/9)

---

If your input doesn't start with a tag then use:

```
((?:(?!\{\w+\}).)*)\{(\w+)\}(.*?){/\2}((?:(?!\{\w+\}).)*)
```

- Group #1 + Group #4 will give you text outside the tags.
- Group #3 will give you text inside the tags.

Comment: What if the text does not start with a tagged group: https://regex101.com/r/HBka56/10?